Does EntityFrameworkCore async method use different thread than the one which DbContext is created?
DBContext db = new DbContext()
await db.Parents.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);

As I know that DBContext is not thread-safe and it does not allow multiple threading, but why can we use await method here? As I understand that await may result in another thread running remaining code. How is it implemented?
Update: Thanks all for helping me understand that await does not mean multiple threading. While I am running below code, it throws out one concurrent exception.
How is multiple threads generated in this senario? Thanks!

A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext

//Inside itemService, it uses DbContext to 
IList<Item> items = itemService.GetItemsForIndexNow();
Task t1 = ExportItemToBingIndexNow(items);
Task t2 = ExportItemToGoogleIndexNow(items);
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
UpdateSubmitCount(items);


private async Task ExportItemToGoogleIndexNow(IList<Item> items)
{
    //...
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, contentData);
    //...
}

//Inside this method, it uses DbContext to update items
private void UpdateSubmitCount(List<Item> items)
{
    foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        item.IndexNowSubmitCount++;
    }
    itemService.FlushAllChanges();
}


I think the test in this case can help you understand await well. Await allows the current thread to be released to do other work but it doesn't mean the rest of the codes will be executed before the task completes, in the opposite, the rest of the codes will be executed after the async task completes. And using await doesn't mean multiple threading... The second version code in the link I shared used multiple threading.

await in C# doesn't inherently introduce multiple threads but rather orchestrates the flow of asynchronous tasks. For this reason, using await with DbContext is safe as long as you don't access the DbContext concurrently from different threads.

Asynchronous doesn't mean multiple threads. IO operations like making IO or network calls or talking to the database are asynchronous - the application itself does nothing while waiting some other service or machine to respond. That doesn't require another thread to wait for that response.

Besides, the reason DbContext doesn't allow concurrent calls is that it's a Unit of Work, not a connection, and actually tracks and controls the objects it loads or persists. The database connections it uses don't allow multiple concurrent queries because the databases don't allow that, at least not with tricky coding that doesn't actually execute stuff in parallel. The queries in a connection run in the same explicit or implied transaction after all. Yes, you can use eg MARS in SQL Server to interleave the results of multiple queries, but those aren't executed in parallel.

This code is parallel:
Task t1 = ExportItemToBingIndexNow(items);
Task t2 = ExportItemToGoogleIndexNow(items);
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);

Already I see that one of these methods is calling ItemService which will be likely "touching" the DbContext:
itemService.FlushAllChanges();

If the two tasks try to access ItemService, or even trigger something like a lazy load on the items passed in from the scoped DbContext if ItemService is using an injected DbContext instance then you will risk encountering problems with cross-thread access to the DbContext.
If you want to update rows based on an export then adjust your worker tasks to not access the ItemService and instead return the IDs/data of items to be updated, processing them all after the Task.WhenAll() completes. That or if you are just updating the tracked Item instances, call SaveChanges() only after the Task.WhenAll() completes.
Task t1 = ExportItemToBingIndexNow(items); // Do not access itemService/DbContext inside
Task t2 = ExportItemToGoogleIndexNow(items);  // Do not access itemService/DbContext inside
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
itemService.FlushAllChanges();

Understanding async/await you need to consider the synchronization context. An easy way to see what is going on in terms of threading:
    [Test]
    public async Task TestRunOuter()
    {
        TestContext.WriteLine($"Thread (start): {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await TestRun();
        TestContext.WriteLine($"Thread (end): {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task TestRun()
    {
        TestContext.WriteLine($"Thread (inner): {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await DoStuff();
    }

    private async Task DoStuff()
    {
        TestContext.WriteLine($"Thread (inside DoStuff): {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            TestContext.WriteLine($"Thread (inside Task.Run): {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        });
    }

Here you can see exactly where threads are handed off with awaited code when an async operation gets resolved and a worker thread is spun up.
Thread (start): 15
Thread (inner): 15
Thread (inside DoStuff): 15
Thread (inside Task.Run): 10
Thread (end): 10 // <= back after our outer "await"

Simply declaring methods as async and even awaiting them doesn't spin off threads. Threads would only be created when a task is handed off to one. await creates a resumption point, and the synchronization context determines if that resumption code needs to operate on the original thread or can resume on the task's thread. (or potentially a different one) Windows forms/WPF apps I believe use a sync context that would resume on the original UI thread for async operations called from that thread. ASP.Net Core does not.
So long as the code is awaited EF is fine if an instance scoped on the starting thread is accessed within the Task.Run (different thread) or after the await completes (still on the different thread). Where it screws up is when we don't await, the code inside the Task.Run will still execute on Thread #10 but the code isn't awaited so Thread #15 will continue with something that might access the DbContext, leading to the multi-thread access exception. In your case having parallelized tasks that are almost certainly "touching" the DbContext result in the same exception.

Hi Steve, thanks for your knowledge very much. In your example code, I see Task.Run(() =>...), I know this is creating a new task. You see my code is also multiple threading, but where is thread created? Thanks!

Yes, it is just a simple example. Any "*Async" flavored framework method will ultimately be executing a Task around an operation. For example db.Parents.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id); FirstOrDefaultAsync performs return ExecuteAsync<TSource, Task<TSource>>(QueryableMethods.FirstOrDefaultWithoutPredicate, source, cancellationToken); Where ExecuteAsync goes down to the specific provider (I.e. SQLServerProvider` to perform the "FirstOrDefault" method in a Task.

So a new thread might be generated inside ExportItemToGoogleIndexNow, right? Like DoStuff, it might be using Task.Run(...) inside ExportItemToGoogleIndexNow or its inner method?

Deep in the bowels of the call stack. If you look at the source for HttpClient.PostAsync it hands off to SendAsync, which then goes down to an HttpMessageInvoker and hands off to an abstract implementation of HttpMessageHandler. Often these classes have a synchronous and asynchronous variant which ultimately has the base level async method calling the synchronous flavour in a Task. (was curious to see that PostAsync isn't actually marked as async)

Thanks Steve for your knowledge! It is clear.

await/async does not cause another thread to start per se. It just means it won't block the program while it waits for the task to complete.
More detailed explanation here: What is the difference between asynchronous programming and multithreading?

This isn't entirely true, it depends on the synchronization context. In ASP.Net Core that context does not require resumption on the original thread. When calling an async method, the resulting task will execute on a different thread and the resumption after the await will typically continue on that alternate thread. This doesn't cause an issue with multiple awaited requests against a DbContext as its thread safety issue is simultaneous requests across different threads.
